# Deploy JavaFX application using gradle 6.3, OpenJDK 14 and OpenJFX 14

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javafx-11

I am developping a JavaFX application using gradle 6.3, OpenJDK 14 and OpenJFX 14 with IntelliJ and I want to deploy it (create a exe file).

I used to make JavaFX applications with JDK 8 under Netbeans 11 and the process was simple:

1. Make the application
2. Clean and build
3. Look for the jar in the dist folder (which works perfectly when I click on it)
4. convert it to exe using Launch4j
5. Voilà!

Since I am migrating to OpenJDK 14, I wanted to make sure I can deploy the app I am making, so I created an application and everything works when I run it (in IntelliJ). I saw some tutorials on how to deploy a javafx app with gradle and I came up to this process:

1. On the gradle window (on the top right of the screen), click on distribution > distZip
2. Look for the generated ZIP file in build\distibutions and unzip it
3. You will find a ***bin*** and ***lib*** folder: In the ***bin*** folder, I have found a **.bat** file of my project and when clicked on it, my app starts and everything works fine. In the ***lib*** folder, I have found all the jar files I used in my project plus my {project-name}.jar and when I click on it nothing happens.

I tried to run it using the command line and here's what I got:

```
    C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SmartDoc\build\distributions\SmartDoc-1.0\SmartDoc-1.0\lib>java -jar SmartDoc-1.0.jar
Table PATIENT created successfully !
Table DOSSIER_MEDICAL created successfully !
Table ORDONNANCE created successfully !
Table RENDEZ_VOUS created successfully !
Table SALLE_ATTENTE created successfully !
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/SmartDoc/build/distributions/SmartDoc-1.0/SmartDoc-1.0/lib/SmartDoc-1.0.jar!/main.fxml:27

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at com.smartdoc.gui.Launch.start(Launch.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:262)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:520)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:370)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:332)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:242)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:775)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.ModuleHelper.invoke(ModuleHelper.java:100)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:258)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fa-user-plus'
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver.resolveIkonHandler(IkonResolver.java:62)
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconLiteral(FontIcon.java:239)
        ... 31 more
```

The first 5 lines are the result of the application creating a derby database (works perfectly), but when it comes to running the app I got some exceptions.
I also tried running with `--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics` but I got the same exceptions.

There is 3 solutions which I know none of them:

1. Solve this exceptions
2. Try to convert that **.bat** file to **.exe** file
3. A new solution

**EDIT:**
build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'com.smartdoc'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.calendarfx:calendar:11.8.3'
    compile 'com.calendarfx:view:11.8.3'
    compile 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-core:11.4.0'
    compile 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:11.4.0'
    compile 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome-pack:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.9'
    compile group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derby', version: '10.15.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derbyclient', version: '10.15.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derbynet', version: '10.15.2.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    version = "14.0.1"
    modules = ['javafx.controls','javafx.fxml']
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/com.smartdoc.Main"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if u wanna get anywhere start easy. Try to get the gradle task "run" to run. This is the task of the application plugin the same plugin that builds the zip.

Comment: Maybe post the build.gradle.

Comment: Also make sure that on your PATH there is an openjdk 14 then. Check output of java -version.

Comment: This project does something similar. Not sure if that helps: https://github.com/FAForever/faf-moderator-client or here a version with install4j and gradle: https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/blob/feature/%231675-update-stuff/build.gradle or a simple one from a private repo: https://gist.github.com/axel1200/9e85054a82da53285cd9e0d282db8f93

Comment: @Alex I added the build.gradle file to my post, the java -version is correct (OpenJDK 14.0.1)

Comment: @Alex Thank you for the projects i will check them right now

Comment: https://github.com/jotoh98/treasureHunt/blob/master/build.gradle is also almost the same

Comment: They are all java 11 but you can run javafx 14 with java 11. And maybe that is a good idea for u as well java 14 is pretty new and 11 is LTS. On the other hand I think nothing should have changed...(when using 14 over 11)

Comment: Did you modularize your own application?

Comment: Do NOT use the     id 'java' plugin, it is already include in the javafx one and it fucks up things.

Comment: If you want to build cross platform you can look into the examples btw.

Comment: And u are gonna have fun with jfoenix and jdk 14 when using some component can not remember which one it was... (so better use 11 :D)

Comment: @Alex thank you for your answers, they have been very helpful, I copied some of the codes and made little modifications to build.gradle, now my .jar file is working like a charm. my next problem is to make an exe from it. Ill post updates when I do something new. And for the jfoenix problem its with JFXTextField (the most important one) apparently it does not work with java > 9 so we have to use something else now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **UPDATE 1:** Making a working .jar file

So I tried some solutions to make my **.jar** file works, and I finally found THE ONE:

1. Add to the top of your **build.gradle** this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

apply plugin : 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

(As you can see I used the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/))

1. In the gradle window (top right of the intelliJ IDE), click **distribution > shadowDistZip**
2. Go to **build\distributions** and you will find a ZIP file ({projectName}-shadow-{version}), unzip it.
3. Open the folder and you will find **bin** and **lib** folders, go to **lib** folder for jar.
4. You will find there your **.jar** that sould work like your expectations.

I am still looking how to make it .exe, so if anyone has a suggestion, welcome!

## **UPDATE 2:** Making a .exe file using Launch4j

I have finally managed to create an **.exe** file from the jar I created previously: I have used [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) (yes, it works with Java > 11). Here's the simple steps:

1. Download [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) first and install it (DONT RUN IT, IT WONT WORK)
2. Go to Launch4j files and you will see a *launch4j.jar* file, run it and select ***Basic*** Tab
3. Select the path where to save the output (make sure you write .exe at the end)
4. Select the path where your **.jar** file is

[image: Quick example]

5. Now go to the ***JRE*** Tab, in the Min JRE version choose 11.0.1 to make sure it starts only with Java > 11, and in the Max JRE version choose the max Java version you want (in my case the last version is 14.0.1

[image: JRE example]

6. Now click on the cog on the top and save the config file wherever you want and Voilà! Your .exe file should be running now perfectly fine.

**P.S.:** You can add an icon, manifest file and many other stuff with Launch4j, I just explained the simpliest example ever just so you guys can make it work, the rest is up to you :)

If there is another solution, please share it with us, many people are suffering with JDK 14 with the executable files.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a gradle plugin for Launch4j IIRC

Comment: @Alex I didn't know it existed, Ill look for it thank you