# Javafx 12 Application Deployment

Tags: javafx, deployment

How to deploy **JavaFx 12+** app as **standalone** application? Every I create JAR file and convert it to .exe using launcher it fails to run. And the error indicates that it lacks JavaFX UI Components, it only works if I use jdk 10 and below. My IDE is IntelliJ Community Edition.

Comment: JavaFX was moved to a separate module in Java 11 (and later). You can use [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) to create a JRE that includes the JavaFX modules, and then use that when you build your .exe. Also note JDK14 include the [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/) tool, which will do both steps (running `jlink` and creating the native package) in one call.

Comment: You can try my solution explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919197/deploy-javafx-application-using-gradle-6-3-openjdk-14-and-openjfx-14/

Answer (score 0):

While JavaFX was moved out of the standard distribution of the JDK/JRE in Java 11, there are still several OpenJDK vendors that produce builds including the JavaFX modules.
Try using a build from Azul or Bellsoft that is marked as "full" or "fx".

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/

Otherwise the solution is to download the JavaFX SDK modules and create a JRE that includes the JavaFX modules with jlink.
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Comment: Thanks, I will try all these two solutions, currently I simply recompile the project with jdk10 though I had to modify the code two a little bit for example everywhere that I used the string.isBlank() method has to be revisited among other ...